# FRP and OEM locks bricked my Samsung phone after root

Tags: samsung, unbricking, locked-out, bootloader-lock, frp

I recently flashed my SM-J701F (Samsung Galaxy J7 Nxt, Android 8.1) with TWRP and Magisk.

Both OEM and RFP locks somehow turned themselves on when I tried to reboot, effectively bricking it by leaving me unable to either boot into any mode or flashing anything using Odin. (Odin always returns FAIL)

It's now asking me to use Smart Switch's emergency recovery feature, but that software refuses to recognize my device too.

Comment: Can you link to instructions you followed for installing and Magisk, and did you deviate from them (perhaps by skipping something)? @BoLawson the boot process would have failed due to twrp and Magisk (device integrity failed), so OP cannot really boot into either of them, thus having access to root is out of scope here.

Comment: @Firelord my mistake, you are correct. // Flashing stock Samsung factory signed firmware of the current or updated android version should not be stopped through odin by the OEM lock. Leading to when Odin fails does it just say fail (if so what point?) Or is there an error along with it like REV. CHECK FAIL(BOOTLOADER) DEVICE: 8, BINARY: 5

Answer (score 1):

Base on my research you can fix the OEM lock by flashing Samsung stock signed firmware using Odin or Samsung tool pro. To remove the frp you need to create a modded boot where the USB debugging is on. You can make one in assayyed kitchen you just need your stock boot, you can get stock boot at the firmware files, let's assume you flash the modded boot. You will boot to your phone but the frp locks is still there what you need to do is connect your phone to your PC then open Samsung tool pro find your phone model there then remove frp using adb.

P.S. Factory data reset your phone after flashing modded boot (optional)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you will either have to talk to a professional or buy a new device.

This is called "bricking" a device: it's now useless, except as a pretty weight. Your phone is soft bricked: possible to recover, but not guaranteed.

There are no conventional methods left to you. Factory reset through recovery isn't an option, fastboot isn't an option, and neither are most standard tools. And you said Odin is not working

Both of my options will cost money, but a professional phone repair person will have access to better tools than you. On that note, it could be costly and even they may not be able to help you. Availability of these services depends on where you are, and your budget